# Query to return the difference of dates between records

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata

I have a table with policy no,status code,status date.

I want to get the difference of the status dates for each policy(will have more than one record with different status codes)after getting sorted with the status dates for each policy.

The difference of the status dates should only consider certain status codes.
for eg: consider that 5,6 are the status codes to be considered

```
pol_nm  st_cd st_date
pol 1   5     1st june
pol 1   6     2nd june
pol 1   7     4th june
pol 1   6     6th june
pol 1   8     9th june
pol 1   9    10th june
pol 1   10   11th june
```

i should get the output as

```
pol_nm  sleep_tm
pol 1     6
```

which is difference of (4th june-1st june)+(9th june-6th june)

Can anyone help me out in quering the output?

Some examples based on new req:

```
Policy_No   Status_Cd       Status_Dt       
A                8      02/01/2011      
A                23     03/30/2011  

Policy_Sleep_Time   0
---------------------------------------------------------

Policy_No   Status_Cd    Status_Dt      
B              8        12/29/2011      
B              27         01/28/2012        
B              27         01/28/2012        124
B              34         05/31/2012    

Policy_Sleep_Time   124
---------------------------------------------------------
Policy_No   Status_Cd    Status_Dt      
C              4        02/11/2007      
C              4        02/11/2007

Policy_Sleep_Time   0
---------------------------------------------------------
Policy_No   Status Cd       Status_Dt
D               8       9/17/2012
D               8       9/17/2012
D               8       9/17/2012
D              23       1/1/2013
D               3       2/1/2013
D               5       2/5/2012
D               23      3/1/2013
D               8       3/6/2013
D               8       3/6/2013
D              44       3/9/2013
D               1       3/23/2013

Here the policy sleep time is 35
```

Comment: Can you put a little more effort in writing your question? Like what are the names of the columns in the table, and what are your output columns?

Comment: column names are policy no,status code,status date.

Comment: Adding one more column for the sleep time. I need to check whether the sleep time is correct or not

Comment: Sleep time is  displayed in a different table where the policy numbers are displayed only once

Comment: How did you pick the record with 4th of june and 1st of june? Using what logic?

Comment: looking the status code. Just taking the sleep time when the policy is the status code of 5 and 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still didn't specify the actual rules, so this cursor-logic is just a guess:

Sort by pol_nm and st_date and then repeat for each pol_nm:

1. find a row with a st_cd of 5 or 6 and remember it's st_date
2. find the next row with a st_cd <> 5/6 and calculate the difference between both st_dates
3. repeat 1 and 2 until you reach the next pol_nm
4. sum the differences

This translates into following SQL

```
SELECT pol_nm, SUM(days)
FROM
 (
   SELECT pol_nm, next_date-MIN(ST_DATE) AS days
   FROM
    (
      SELECT pol_nm, ST_CD, ST_DATE,
        MIN(CASE WHEN ST_CD NOT IN (5,6) THEN ST_DATE END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY pol_nm 
              ORDER BY ST_DATE
              ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS next_date
      FROM tab
      QUALIFY ST_DATE <> next_date 
    ) AS dt
   GROUP BY pol_nm, next_date
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY pol_nm
```

Dieter

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Dieter!  I'm really glad to see you here!

Comment: Hi Dieter, i have some changes in the requirement.

Comment: Now i have one table named policy.

In the policy table several fields are there, but i am concentrating on policyno,status code and status change date.
And sleep time needs to get calculated from those.
If the status codes 23 and 27 are present for a policy, then the policy should get displayed with sleep time , otherwise not

Eg: 
Policy_No Status_Cd Status_Dt  
A 8 02/01/2011  
A 23 03/30/2011  
   Policy_Sleep_Time 0

Comment: I have given the examples in my question above. Can you please take a look?

Comment: You still didn't specify any rules and i my crystal ball didn't tell me, too. So could you please specify an algorithm how this sleep time should be calculated.

Comment: 1. Check for all the records of a policy.

Comment: 2. Check wethr the status is 5 or 6, if then calculate the days till the next status where it comes other than 5 or 6. Again check for the remaining records of the same policy. And add all the sleep days.

Comment: 3. If a policy is not having the status as 5 or 6, then the policy shouldnt get displayed.

Comment: 4. If a policy is having the status 5 or 6, but if no remaining records has any other status, then sleep days should be zero.

Comment: 5. Ultimately we are finding the inactive/pending days of a policy. When the policy is having the status of 5 or 6 doesnot get changed to any other state, means the policy is still inactive, so displaying as zero. I need the policy with sleep days(days when the policy was in inactive status before it became active)

Comment: I have given some examples above in the query

Comment: In the examples which i have given, instead of 5 and 6, 23 and 27 are taken as the pending status

Comment: Your narration is still quite confusing, but the answer i postet should be close.

Comment: but i am not getting the actual result. The sum of the days are nowhere related

Comment: I understood the prob. Some NULLs are there in the status codes. I need omit that too.